# Jquery: how to do a callback after attr?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change the img src at first then accomplish others. Something like this-

```
$('#bgImage').attr('src','images/'+bgImage, function() {
    alert('inside');
});
```

how will i do that?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do that on a callback instead of the suggested solutions?

Comment: ya. for big images, I want load it first

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another line of code perhaps?

```
$('#bgImage').attr('src','images/'+bgImage),
$('#searchPin').css("top",y+"px");
$('#searchPin').css("left",x+"px");
```

If you want to wait for the image to load, you're probably looking for the event [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

```
$('#bgImage').load(function() {
    $('#searchPin').css("top",y+"px");
    $('#searchPin').css("left",x+"px");
}).attr('src','images/'+bgImage);
```

Note that the `load(...)` event handler was created before changing the `src` attribute using `attr` - in case the image has been cached.

If you're doing this more than once you might want to look into [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) too.

Comment: I believe you should bind the load before you change the src, for cases where the destination is already cached.

Comment: best to `bind` the handler to the `load` event before changing the `src` attribute. That is because if the image is cached then it will be loaded before you attach the handler and it will not be called.. You should also chain the two calls to the same element, or better yet since both are to the `css` method use the object parameter that accepts multiple options to change `.css({top:y+'px', left:x+'px'})`

Comment: @Matt - That's a good point. I will change the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli - I agree, but I'm going to leave the `.css(...)` as is, since it's not what's specifically been asked.

Answer (score 9):

When you change the image's source, it will be loaded, and will fire an onload event when it is done.  So:

```
$('#bgImage').attr('src','images/'+bgImage).load(function() {
    $('#searchPin').css("top",y+"px");
    $('#searchPin').css("left",x+"px");
});
```

Comment: best to `bind` the handler to the  `load` event before changing the `src` attribute. That is because if the image is cached then it will be loaded before you attach the handler and it will not be called.. You should also chain the two calls to the same element, or better yet since both are to the `css` method use the object parameter that accepts multiple options to change `.css({top:y+'px', left:x+'px'})`

Comment: Worked for me very well :)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

`.attr` is executed immediately. More than likely what you actually need is to wait until the image is done loading, then do something.

```
var $img = $("#bgImage");    
$img.load(function(){
    // image is done loading, do something
    alert("worky (not cached)")
});
$img.attr('src','images/' + bgImage);
```

Comment: @Matt That I don't know for sure; the code for the cache check wasn't originally from me, it came from this forum post: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/wait-until-all-images-are-loaded

Comment: @Matt Hmm... actually it didn't come from there. I have no idea then.

Comment: I get the feeling it originally came from some confusion between the XMLHTTPRequest.readyState and the `<img />`'s complete... I'd bet money on it not existing.

Comment: Very interesting. Haven't got IE9 here, but I take your word for it :P