# Jquery Animations not waiting for callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, jquery-callback

I have a Jquery animation that is running the code from its function before the animation is complete.  the Page this code is being used at is no where near complete yet but if you want to take a look it's cottageboards.com/orderform

```
$('#snow').fadeIn(500, "linear", function () {
    $('#largeImage').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#largeImage').attr('src', selectedimg).load(function () {
            $('#largeImage').fadeIn(1000, function () {

//Everything below here is running before the above image's fade in is complete


                $('#snow').fadeOut(5000);
                var selection = 'input[name="' + $(selectionage).data('type') + '_selection"]';
                $($('#selected_thumb').val()).attr('src', $($('#selected_thumb').val()).data('regular'));
                $(selectionage).attr('src', $(selectionage).data('selected'));
                selectedid = '#' + $(selectionage).attr('id');
                $('#selected_thumb').val(selectedid);
                $('#selected_info').html($(selectionage).data('desc'));
                $('#name').html($(selectionage).data('name'));
                if ($(selectionage).data('val') === 99) {
                    $('#upload').show();
                    $('#displayinfo').hide();
                } else {
                    $(selection).val($(selectionage).data('val'));
                    $('#upload').hide();
                    $('#displayinfo').show();
                }
                $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When rewritten so the load function comes before the src change it works like a charm. Thanks for the help guys!

Working code:

```
$('#snow').fadeIn(500, "linear", function () {
    $('#largeImage').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#largeImage').unbind().load(function () {
            $('#largeImage').fadeIn(1000, function () {
                $('#snow').fadeOut(5000);
                var selection = 'input[name="' + $(selectionage).data('type') + '_selection"]';
                $($('#selected_thumb').val()).attr('src', $($('#selected_thumb').val()).data('regular'));
                $(selectionage).attr('src', $(selectionage).data('selected'));
                selectedid = '#' + $(selectionage).attr('id');
                $('#selected_thumb').val(selectedid);
                $('#selected_info').html($(selectionage).data('desc'));
                $('#name').html($(selectionage).data('name'));
                if ($(selectionage).data('val') === 99) {
                    $('#upload').show();
                    $('#displayinfo').hide();
                } else {
                    $(selection).val($(selectionage).data('val'));
                    $('#upload').hide();
                    $('#displayinfo').show();
                }
                $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
            });
        }).attr('src', selectedimg);
    });
});
```

Comment: you should define the onload function before setting the src attribute.

Comment: use done() function in fadein look at this doc: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: @r3wt so you're saying  $('#largeimage').load (function (){code to wait till new source is loaded here}).attr ('src', newsource);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the load function to largeimage every time you click.  The first click the load function gets called once, the second time, it gets called twice.  I suspect everything is getting messed up because you are firing multiple .fadeIns on the same object, and they are running in parallel.

Only call `$('#largeImage').load(...)` once, not on every click.  Of course, you'll have to do something about your captured vars, but that's a different issue.  Alternatively, call `$('#largeImage').unbind().load(...)`

If that's hard to follow, replace this line:

```
$('#largeImage').attr('src', selectedimg).load(function () {
```

with:

```
$('#largeImage').unbind().attr('src', selectedimg).load(function () {
```

I tested it by putting a break point after this line:

```
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function() {
```

and calling `$('#largeImage').unbind();` and everything seemed to work, so you can do it that way too.

Comment: I think you have it nailed. I do think you should bind the load before changing the src, for cases where the destination is already cached. If the destination is in cache when you set the source attribute, the image loads before the `.load` event is attached and won't fire. Little bit about it here in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7850962/933633

Comment: This is it. Unbind combined with putting the load function before the src change made this work exactly how I wanted

Answer (score 0):

see this fiddle for example how to use `done` : http://jsfiddle.net/gcnes8b2/1/

```
$('span').click(function() {
    $('#1').fadeIn({
        duration: 1000,
        done:function(){
            $('#2').fadeOut(1000);
            // etc
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the built in `complete` callback feature?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-options complete:A function that is called once the animation on an element is complete. done: A function to be called when the animation on an element completes. so done() is more global i think, but back its just the same thing

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had the same question as paparazzokid. The builtin callback was enough for me one the load function was in the right place